# New Lufthansa API - can't get token

Tags: r, api, httr

Can someone guide me in how to get access to the Lufthansa API?  I have taken a good starting point and modified the original code line my line with checks at each step.

Steps 1 and 2 appear to work

```
library(httr)
library(httpuv)
#Original code taken from 
#https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/master/demo/oauth2-github.r

# 1. Set OAuth settings for dlh:
# http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/functions/oauth2.0_token.html
dlh = oauth_endpoint(
        base_url = "https://api.lufthansa.com/v1/oauth",
        request = NULL,
        authorize = "authorize",
        access = "token"
)

# 2. Register an application 
#    Replace key and secret below.
# http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/functions/oauth_app
myapp <- oauth_app("SampleCabin",
                   key = "****",
                   secret = "****")
```

But then I get into problems

```
options(httr_oauth_cache=TRUE, httr_oob_default=TRUE)

# 3. Get OAuth credentials
# http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/functions/oauth2.0_token
#Sample 
#oauth2.0_token(endpoint, app, scope = NULL, user_params = NULL,
               #type = NULL, use_oob = getOption("httr_oob_default"),           as_header = TRUE, use_basic_auth = FALSE, cache = getOption("httr_oauth_cache"))

dlh_token <- oauth2.0_token(dlh, myapp, 
                            scope =          "https://api.lufthansa.com/v1/oauth/token",
                            use_oob = getOption("httr_oob_default"), 
                            use_basic_auth = FALSE#,
                            )
```

I get the following message.

```
#Please point your browser to the following url: 
#https://api.lufthansa.com/v1/oauth/authorize?client_id=****&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.lufthansa.com%2Fv1%2Foauth%2Ftoken&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code

#Enter authorization code:
```

Now I thought that the above line of code was to get a token.  Instead at this point I have to manually paste in a token taken from scope URL.  What am I doing wrong here?

This is followed by an error message.

```
#Error in init_oauth2.0(self$endpoint, self$app, scope = self$params$scope,        Bad Request (HTTP 400).
```

I plan to follow this with the following...

```
# 4. Use API
req <-  GET("https://api.lufthansa.com/v1/operations/flightstatus/route/TLS/FRA/2016-02-15",config(token = dlh_token))

stop_for_status(req)
content(req)
```

This is the first time I have tried to access an API other than following exercises.  Just to make things more interesting I think I will need to add a proxy address somewhere in the process (step 4 I think).

Any ideas??

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Don't authorize and access have to be URLs? from the oauth_endpoint help file:

authorize
url to send client to for authorisation

access
url used to exchange unauthenticated for authenticated token.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Sharon! I am not really sure what I need to change! [developer.lufthansa.com/docs/read/api_basics/Getting_Started ](developer.lufthansa.com) gives api.lufthansa.com/v1/oauth/token as the url to get the token.